# Do I need to go through multiple immigration when changing Schengen country?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, schengen, schengen-visas, spain, netherlands

So I finally got the Schengen visa from Netherlands. I'll stay 3 days in Netherlands and 3-4 days in Spain. I wanted to know if I need to go through immigration process again in Spain? Or only at the Netherlands i.e. my entry point in Schengen area.

Answer (score 12):

You will only go through immigration on your first entry to Schengen.  As a visitor, you can almost regard Schengen as a single country.  Rather like going between states in the USA or provinces in Canada.

However, watch out for a few things.

A trip through a non-Schengen country e.g. a flight with a change in the UK.

Not all EU countries are in Schengen e.g. Ireland.

You might encounter an ID check even within a country so carry your ID.

Comment: ID checks are rare in most places (exceptions: international airports and train-stations and near government centers). But not being able to produce ID when asked can get you in serious trouble (stiff fines, being detained until your ID is confirmed in some cases). Always carry ID. If you are worried about pickpockets you can usually get away with a photocopy of your ID and leave the real ID in the hotel-safe. (It is technically not permitted, but in most cases police officers will accept it.)

Comment: Thanks for the expanded detail.  I did not intend to suggest that checks are common or likely, just that they could occur.  The only time that I have been checked is a ticket inspection (some trains), hotel check-in, and car rental.  I have never been stopped by the police and asked for ID.   I look stereotypically European but wife does not look and she has also never been asked for ID.

Comment: I personally only got asked once (London near the government buildings, where they checked everyone), but over the last 10 years my colleague (who is from Middle Eastern decent and looks the part) experienced dozens of ID checks. In 3 cases (Amsterdam airport, Paris subway and Geneva airport) it actually happened while I was with him on a business trip. They only wanted to see his ID, not mine. I'm Caucasian myself, but I have several dark-skinned family members (from Indonesia and Suriname) who have similar stories. Racial profiling happens a lot more than people want to admit...

Comment: @Tonny: Is that really the case? At least in Germany, there is only an obligation to *have* ID but not to carry it with you in public. However, police may detain you for identification purposes at their discretion whenever they have a legal basis to identify you (which is generally the case at airports, interregional train stations, or near international borders). Thus, carrying *some* form of ID, even a copy or an unofficial ID, would likely satisfy that need and avoid detainment.

Comment: Thanks a lot, guys. I'm very excited as well as nervous at the same time. I hope everything goes fine :) I really appreciate your help.

Comment: No need to be nervous.  You can almost regard this as a trip within your own country.  You probably won't meet many Polish speakers but there will be plenty of English speakers.